# Add fragment into react-native view

Tags: android, android-fragments, react-native, fragmentmanager

Long story short: I'm trying to create a native module for an react-native project for AndroidPay. Integration of AndroidPay is possible only using fragments (which are in final "Buy with AndroidPay" buttons). So the algorithm is pretty simple, export a placeholder in react-native, wrap it in a component and at some point just add fragment into that placeholder using it's id. So the code looks like:

```
public class AndroidPayPlaceholderViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<FrameLayout>{
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "AndroidPayButton";

    public AndroidPayPlaceholderViewManager(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected FrameLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(reactContext).inflate(R.layout.android_pay_frg_placeholder, null);
    }
}
```

android_pay_placeholder.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/android_pay_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

js component wrapper

```
import {View, requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NativeModules, findNodeHandle} from 'react-native';
import {isAndroid} from '../utils';


let iface = {
    propTypes: {
        ...View.propTypes, // include the default view properties
        foo: String
    }
};

let AndroidPayButtonNative = requireNativeComponent('NewStoreAndroidPayButton', iface);
console.log('AndroidPayButtonNative: ', AndroidPayButtonNative);
let AndroidPayModule = isAndroid() ? NativeModules.NewStoreAndroidPay : null;

class AndroidPayButton extends Component {
    state = {
        loaded: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        AndroidPayModule.loadFragment();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AndroidPayButtonNative {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}

export {AndroidPayButton};
```

android native module which is in charge of loading the fragment

```
public class AndroidPayModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener, LifecycleEventListener {
....
@ReactMethod
    public void loadFragment(int placeholderId) {
        ...
        WalletFragment mWalletFragment = WalletFragment.newInstance(...);


        // add Wallet fragment to the UI
        getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.android_pay_placeholder, mWalletFragment)
                .commit();

        // [END params_builder]
    }
....
}
```

So, when I add the "placeholder" view to the screen I can see it and even checked with LayoutInspector, the id is right:

[image]

And the result that I always get is exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00a6 (com.qwerty.playground:id/android_pay_placeholder) for fragment WalletFragment{388fd9c #0 id=0x7f0d00a6}
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:965)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)        
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So guys, any idea why FragmentManager can't just find a view which definitely exists and maybe someone of you did this trick with fragments and react-native and succeeded? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: hi @fox, did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Hey @Andy, yes, but I don't remember now in which mode because I removed it and done it in another way. The reason was that it was unstable and you have to handle too many situations (add/remove fragment), a lot of checks. So I would recommend to avoid this way as much as possible.