# React Native : add fragment to mainactivity using Android Native Modules

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native, fragmentmanager

I have a specific Android native library to integrate the camera features. The library provides the Fragment with the all it features. I just want to integrate that with Mainactivity in React Native app.

I have followed the link ["Add fragment into react-native view"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613449/add-fragment-into-react-native-view)

Also i have gone through many [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221447/react-native-inside-a-fragment). But I am stuck up at the place where we add the fragment into the Mainactivity container layout of React native app.

**Update:**

**React Component (JS file):**

```
export default class MyCustomView extends Component {
render() {
   return (
      <View >
       {
        MyLayout.openBlankFragment(12345)

       }
      </View>
   );
  }
  }
 const MyLayout = NativeModules.MyModule;
```

**MyModule (Java Code):**

```
@ReactMethod
    private void openBlankFragment(final int viewId) {
//        Log.v("View Tag", "View ID: "+viewId); it prints tag 12345
        UIManagerModule uiManager = getReactApplicationContext().getNativeModule(UIManagerModule.class);

                uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock() {
            @Override
            public void execute(NativeViewHierarchyManager nativeViewHierarchyManager) {
                View view = nativeViewHierarchyManager.resolveView(viewId);

                final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
                BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = ((MainActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(view.getId(), fragment);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }
```

**view.getId()** is not recognized. Need help here. If i set the activity root view id like "transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);". Its working fine and i can my fragment. But i need to setup my fragment as view in React screen like a frame.

Comment: What is the meaning of stuck? Errors? Logs? Problems? Code?

Comment: @sfratini I have updated my code. Need to get the react native view code at android native module. i stuck up there. :(